# is it possible to deallocate a static variable manually in swift?

Tags: swift, memory

I need to store a static variable only one time when app is launched, and that to for short period of time.

i want to deallocate that static variable once it's use is over.

Comment: Make it optional, and set it to `nil` when you are done.

Comment: yes, i can make it to nil, this didn't cross my mind.
Thanx btw!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, static variables can be declared with `var` and made optional with `?`, just like instance and local variables.

```
class Y { }

class X {
    static weak var myOptionalStaticThing:Y? = Y()

    func foo() {
        // X.myOptionalStaticThing gets deallocated after this
        // if this were the only strong pointer to X.myOptionalStaticThing
        X.myOptionalStaticThing = nil
    }
}
```